# How add box shadow to a div inside a container ? (Image included)

Tags: html, css

the image says what I want to do

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what your question is

Comment: Have you tried absolutely positioning the div with the box shadow?

Comment: Bialy ... not having a proper text description of the issue makes this not that useful for people who happen upon this question in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

- Put some margin on the top one's left side
- Remove overflow-hidden from the grey div
- Postion the top box with position:relative, and increase the z-index

Comment: well, after some search, there was a bigger container div (containing the gray one) with hidden overflow.
Thanks Rich :)

Comment: It's always one of those three!

Answer (score 0):

this might help:

```
{
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius:5px;

-moz-box-shadow: 3px black;
-webkit-box-shadow:3px black;
box-shadow:3px black;
}
```

Comment: I suspect that the "this is what happens" box includes this CSS already.